# Prove that $\left(x + \sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^3 \le (x + a)(x + b)(x + c) \le \left( x + \frac{a + b + c}{3} \right)^3.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

Let $x,$ $a,$ $b,$ $c$ be nonnegative real numbers. Prove that $$\left(x + \sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^3 \le (x + a)(x + b)(x + c) \le \left( x + \frac{a + b + c}{3} \right)^3.$$

I've tried using AM-GM by splitting the inequality into two inequalities, but I got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

I had an idea of removing x from all sides. Would that be helpful or no?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: right inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz (or AM-GM) with $x+a, x+b, x+c$. left inequality is straight-forward if you expand both sides and also use AM-GM on the respective $x$-component.

Comment: I had an idea of removing $x$ from all sides. Would that be helpful or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left inequality it's just Holder:
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)\geq\left(\sqrt[3]{x\cdot x\cdot x}+\sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^3=\left(x+\sqrt[3]{abc}\right)^3.$$
The right inequality is true by AM-GM:
$$(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)\leq\left(\frac{x+a+x+b+x+c}{3}\right)^3=\left(x+\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3.$$

Comment: Where you say "Holder", I think you mean "Mahler's inequality".

Comment: @Blitzer I think Holder is better because the Mahler's inequality follows immediately from Holder. By the way Holder was 50 years older  than Mahler. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something. Wiki says Holder is $$\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k\,y_k| \le \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p \biggr)^{\frac{1}{p}} \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^n |y_k|^q \biggr)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$. Which doesn't look the same to me.

Comment: @Blitzer This Holder in the sado-mazo form! The human's Holder see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/holder-inequality/info I hope, now you see that we don't need  the Huygens's inequality, the Mahler's inequality and more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea works!

The left inequality.

We need to prove that:
$$  x^3+3\sqrt[3]{abc}x^2+3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}x+abc\leq x^3+(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+ac+bc)x+abc,$$
which is true by AM-GM:
$$a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc}$$ and
$$ab+ac+bc\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}.$$
The right inequality we can prove by the similar way.

Comment: And these didn't fit into a single post because?